# Zk Framework : How Escape HTML from tooltip?

Tags: html, tooltip, zk

I am using below code

```
<label  value="${comment.folderCommentRecord.comments}"  tooltiptext="${comment.folderCommentRecord.comments}"></label>
```

But **tooltiptext** attribute not able to escape html character for showing the data i am using below code and its able to escape html charters

```
<html>
    <x:div style="overflow:hidden;height:20px;">
    <![CDATA[${comment.folderCommentRecord.comments}
                                        ]]>
    </x:div>
</html>
```

Anyone please guide me how to escape html from tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
<html>

 <![CDATA[
    <x:label title="${comment.folderCommentRecord.comments}">${comment.folderCommentRecord.comments}</x:label>

  ]]>

  </html>
```